# Java program not saving object to HashMap

Tags: java, object, hashmap

Either my `save_product` function in my `Repository.java` class doesn't save correctly into the map `product_repository` or, maybe it does save, but I'm not outputting it correctly in my `find_product` function in my `Repository.java` class. I think I'm using the correct function to search for the value in the map, `.get`

I experimented with `product_repository.keySet().iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);` but that's the first time I ever used that... also please forgive how I insert the `key`into the map `product_repository` in the `create_new_product` function in the `Controller.java` class. I'm new to java ...

Main.java

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.create_new_product();
        controller.search_product();
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
package com.company;

public class Product {
    private String product_name;
    private String product_brand;
    private int product_cost;
    private int product_count;
    private boolean product_availability;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String product_name, String product_brand,
                   int product_cost, int product_count, boolean product_availability) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_brand = product_brand;
        this.product_cost = product_cost;
        this.product_count = product_count;
        this.product_availability = product_availability;
    }

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public String getProduct_brand() {
        return product_brand;
    }

    public void setProduct_brand(String product_brand) {
        this.product_brand = product_brand;
    }

    public int getProduct_cost() {
        return product_cost;
    }

    public void setProduct_cost(int product_cost) {
        this.product_cost = product_cost;
    }

    public int getProduct_count() {
        return product_count;
    }

    public void setProduct_count(int product_count) {
        this.product_count = product_count;
    }

    public boolean isProduct_availability() {
        return product_availability;
    }

    public void setProduct_availability(boolean product_availability) {
        this.product_availability = product_availability;
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {
    private static Long key;

    public static void create_new_product(){
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        //Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
        Product product = new Product();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        key = 0L;

        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("********************NEW PRODUCT CREATION PAGE********************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");

        System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        product.setProduct_name(name);

        System.out.println("Enter product brand: ");
        String brand = scanner.nextLine();
        product.setProduct_brand(brand);

        System.out.println("Enter product cost: ");
        int cost = scanner.nextInt();
        product.setProduct_cost(cost);

        System.out.println("Enter amount of products in stock: ");
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        product.setProduct_count(amount);

        key++;
        repository.save_product(key, product);
    }

    public void search_product(){
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        Product product = new Product();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("*************************FIND PRODUCT PAGE***********************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        // TO DO: Choices or if/else blocks not executing properly
        System.out.println("\nSearch by ID or name?\nPress '1' for ID. Press '2' for name: ");
        String choice = scanner.next();
        if (choice.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Enter product id: ");
            Long id = scanner.nextLong();
            repository.find_product(id);

            try{
                if (product.getProduct_count() > 0){
                    System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are in stock!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are out of stock.");
            }
        }

        else if (choice.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
            String name = scanner.next();
            repository.find_product(name);

            try{
                if (product.getProduct_count() > 0){
                    System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are in stock!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are out of stock.");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error. We apologize for the inconvenience.");
        }
    }
}
```

Repository.java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Repository {
    private Map<Long, Product> product_repository = new HashMap<Long, Product>();

    // TO DO: Implement while loops so program doesn't exit at the first error

    public void save_product(Long key, Product newProductMap){
        try{
            if (product_repository.containsValue(newProductMap)) {
                System.out.println("This product is already in the system." +
                        "\nFor safety reasons, we cannot add the same product twice.");
            }
            else {
                product_repository.put(key, newProductMap);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("System error. Consult the database administrator.");
        }
    }

    public void find_product(Long key){
        try {
            if (product_repository.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println(product_repository.get(key));
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No matches were found for product id: " + key);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("System error. Consult the database administrator.");
        }
    }

    // Overload
    public void find_product(String name) {
        try {
            if (product_repository.containsValue(name)) {
                System.out.println(product_repository.get(name));
                product_repository.keySet().iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No matches were found for product name: " + name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("System error. Consult the database administrator.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make `Repository repository` a field of your `Controller` class. You are currently throwing the repositories away after your methods `create_new_product` and `search_product` have executed. Therefore you need to remove the first line of each of these methods.

Another problem is inside your `find_product(String name)` method where your call `product_repository.get(name)` but name is a `String` and the `get` method expects an ID, i.e. a `Long` so this call will always return `null`.

Comment: Problem has been solved, I appreciate you taking the time to help me with my program!

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out before the repository has to be made global. However, the entire code is a bit messy. You are searching for a product id but the id is not shown to you. It is like searching for database records but the ids are autogenerated. Good luck with that. So I would suggest to allow this program to enter the id as well. It makes much more sense if you want to search for the id.
Otherwise, if you are interested in only the value, id can be taken out.
Below you can find the modified code that works for all the methods.

```
 //main stays the same
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.create_new_product();
        controller.search_product();
    }

}


 //controller is a bit changed. Added global repository and improved the search.
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {
    private static Long key;

    Repository repository = new Repository();

    public void create_new_product() {
        Product product = new Product();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("********************NEW PRODUCT CREATION PAGE********************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Enter product id: ");
        long id = Long.parseLong(scanner.nextLine());
        product.setProductId(id);

        System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        product.setProduct_name(name);

        System.out.println("Enter product brand: ");
        String brand = scanner.nextLine();
        product.setProduct_brand(brand);

        System.out.println("Enter product cost: ");
        int cost = scanner.nextInt();
        product.setProduct_cost(cost);

        System.out.println("Enter amount of products in stock: ");
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        product.setProduct_count(amount);

        repository.save_product(id, product);
    }

    public void search_product() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("*************************FIND PRODUCT PAGE***********************");
        System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
        // TO DO: Choices or if/else blocks not executing properly
        System.out.println("\nSearch by ID or name?\nPress '1' for ID. Press '2' for name: ");
        String choice = scanner.next();
        if (choice.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Enter product id: ");
            Long id = scanner.nextLong();
            Product product = repository.find_product(id);

            try {
                if (product.getProduct_count() > 0) {
                    System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are in stock!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are out of stock.");
            }
        } else if (choice.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
            String name = scanner.next();
            Collection<Product> products = repository.find_products(name);

            if (products.size() > 0) {
                for (Product product : products) {
                    System.out.println(product.getProduct_name() + " are in stock!");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(" out of stock.");

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error. We apologize for the inconvenience.");
        }
    }
}


//Added a new field to the Repository so you can also search by key.
import java.util.*;

public class Repository {
    private Map<Long, Product> product_repository = new HashMap<Long, Product>();

    // TO DO: Implement while loops so program doesn't exit at the first error

    public void save_product(Long key, Product newProductMap) {
        try {
            if (!product_repository.containsKey(key)) {
                product_repository.put(key, newProductMap);
            } else {
                System.out.println("This product is already in the system." +
                        "\nFor safety reasons, we cannot add the same product twice.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("System error. Consult the database administrator.");
        }
    }

    public Product find_product(final Long key) {
        try {
            if (product_repository.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println("Found product: " + product_repository.get(key).getProduct_name());
                return product_repository.get(key);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No matches were found for product id: " + key);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("System error. Consult the database administrator.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Overload
    public Collection<Product> find_products(final String name) {
        Collection<Product> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Product> productEntry : product_repository.entrySet()) {
            if (productEntry.getValue().getProduct_name().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println("matches were found for product name: " + name);
                values.add(productEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to help me, the generous code example was unexpected but very appreciated! The problem is solved. Thanks once again!